# android-tv Changing text color and font of browse fragment rows header

Tags: android-tv, leanback

How to change text color and font of rows header in browse fragment?.
The text not in menu but the text that appears above the rows.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the provided `android.support.v17.leanback.widget.RowHeaderPresenter` as the presenter for the `HeaderFragment` in your `BrowseFragment`.

The `RowHeaderPresenter` inflates the layout from `R.layout.lb_row_header` which looks like this:

```
<android.support.v17.leanback.widget.RowHeaderView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/row_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?rowHeaderStyle" />
```

As you can see, this uses a style attribute called `rowHeaderStyle`, which is normally pointing to `@style/Widget.Leanback.Row.Header`. You can override this by putting the following in your `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="MyCustomRowHeaderStyle" parent="Widget.Leanback.Row.Header">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomBrowseStyle" parent="Theme.Leanback.Browse">
    <item name="rowHeaderStyle">@style/MyCustomRowHeaderStyle</item>
</style>
```

And then use `MyCustomBrowseStyle` for the `Activity` containing the `BrowseFragment` by declaring it in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 6):

*In addition to David's answer.*

`rowHeaderStyle` applies the style both to menu items in `HeaderFragment` and row titles in `RowFragment` (these two fragments compose your `BrowseFragment`).

If you want their styles (font colors in particular) to be different, you can override `BrowseFragment::onCreateHeadersFragment()` and apply specific theme at that point.

1) Add these styles to `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Leanback.Browse.Row" parent="@style/Theme.Leanback.Browse">
    <item name="rowHeaderStyle">@style/AppTheme.Leanback.Row</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Leanback.Browse.Header" parent="@style/AppTheme.Leanback.Browse.Row">
    <item name="rowHeaderStyle">@style/AppTheme.Leanback.Header</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Leanback.Row" parent="Widget.Leanback.Row.Header">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/font_row</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Leanback.Header" parent="Widget.Leanback.Row.Header">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/font_header</item>
</style>
```

2) Apply `AppTheme.Leanback.Browse.Row` theme to your activity in manifest.

3) Apply `AppTheme.Leanback.Browse.Header` theme to headers in your `BrowseFragment`:

```
// Kotlin snippet
override fun onCreateHeadersFragment() : HeadersFragment {
    class CustomHeadersFragment : HeadersFragment() {
        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
            return super.onCreateView(
                    inflater.cloneInContext(ContextThemeWrapper(inflater.context, R.style.AppTheme_Leanback_Browse_Header)),
                    container,
                    savedInstanceState
            )
        }
    }

    return CustomHeadersFragment()
}
```

Comment: I couldn't find where override to `onCreateHeadersFragment`. Apparently I was running an older version of leanback, this method has recently been added to 25.3.0. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/BrowseFragment.html#onCreateHeadersFragment()

Answer (score 4):

The answer by david.mihola helps with the color, however I still had problems with setting a custom font globally. For everybody who stumbles upon this question and is puzzled about this as well, here is my solution:

Thanks to the awesome work done by [chrisjenx (Calligraphy)](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy), you can easily set a global (custom) font.

Simply add Calligraphy to your gradle.build and add the following snippet to your `Application.onCreate()`:

```
CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                        .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/MyCustomFont.ttf")
                        .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                        .build()
        );
```

and in every Activity add the following:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

This has done the font-trick for me on every single TextView, without modifying layouts. The documentation of Calligraphy also offers some more possibilities. Check it out.

I hope this helps other people who find this question and are trying to set (custom) fonts globally.