# Set background color of selected main menu item of BrowseFragment

Tags: android, leanback

I am using Leanback BrowseFragment and need to be able to set background colour of header item when selected. Any direct method/XML attributes available to do that? I have been looking into BrowseFragment and leanback themes.xml.

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/BrowseFragment.html
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v17/leanback/res/values/themes.xml

Comment: You may find a hints in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774150/android-tv-changing-text-color-and-font-of-browse-fragment-rows-header

Comment: May be I also encounter the same case as you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500898/how-to-rounder-corner-on-children-of-row-use-leanback-listrowpresenter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500898/how-to-rounder-corner-on-children-of-row-use-leanback-listrowpresenter)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used custom header items with icons. You can see details in [this](http://corochann.com/browsefragment-header-customization-android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-17-697.html) tutorial. For TextView from my layout I defined `xml` file in the `color` directory, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/accent_color" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:color="@color/white"/>
</selector>
```

and the same xml files (but with `android:drawable` attributes )  in the direcroty `drawable`.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_focused"
     android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon"/>
</selector>
```

Then simply set `android:textColor="@color/your_new_xml_file"` for `TextView`and use your drawable files for your header `ImageView`.

If you need to change `View` background, not only header icon and text color, set such `xml` file with defined colors as a `View` background.

OnSelectLevelChanged() method in my presenter class is empty (without this, like in tutorial above) :

```
holder.view.setAlpha(mUnselectedAlpha + holder.getSelectLevel() *
                (1.0f - mUnselectedAlpha));
```