# How to customise Header Item of Row in android leanback library?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

[image]

I am new in Android TV development.

I use android leanback library for this. Also I I use BrowseSupportFragment and RowsSupportFragmen.

Here I want to customise the HeaderItem shown in the picture.

Specially I want to change its font. I check lots of things but not getting proper solution for this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `BrowseSupportFragment` you can use method  `setHeaderPresenterSelector()` and register own presenter for headers. It should inherard from `RowHeaderPresenter`

If you want to override all header at once then you can create file
`res/values/layout/lb_row_header.xml` and redefine layout for default header presenter.

Comment: I think  setHeaderPresenterSelector is for left side drawer header not for this one which i mention in the question.

Comment: Here I am Using RowsSupportFragment

Comment: Yes setHeaderPresenterSelector is for left side drawer.

Comment: @sohel.eco i've you got any solution for this, I'm also looking for that solution

Comment: @Harish I  did lots of r&d about that but not got any solution. Also one thing I see in TV app development,  in all cases of TV development apps there is no customisation. Leanback library give lots of functionalities as it is default and less customisation is available in that

Comment: @sohel.eco, I've followed, this link and achieved the text with icon..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46198605/androidtv-change-color-of-rows-header-browsefragment                                                                                                              and also in this below URL they told how to change the text font also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41780279/android-tv-how-to-change-color-of-title-and-color-of-headeritem            font i didn't try.

Comment: Hi Guys, i am new to android leanback, anybody has an idea, that how to stop header(left side) animation in browse fragment ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 override fun onBindRowViewHolder(holder: RowPresenter.ViewHolder?, item: Any?) {
    super.onBindRowViewHolder(holder, item)
    val textView = holder?.headerViewHolder?.view?.findViewById<RowHeaderView>(R.id.row_header)
    textView?.run {
        setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12.5f)
        isAllCaps = true
        setFontFamily(context, R.font.hind_bold)
    }
 }
```

Comment: If you enabled non-transitive R classes, use `androidx.leanback.R.id.row_header`